# Starting SQLAlchemy session from separate file

Tags: sqlalchemy

I created my models in a file and can successfully add and alter objects which successfully commit to the database when run in a function beneath the model declaration.  When I import my Session and model classes into a separate script, I can successfully run a query, but if I update the object and run an update the db does not get updated.  The same code works well when run beneath where I defined my models and I'm totally confused why this is.  Am I confused as to how I should work with and update my database?

Comment: Please provide some code examples (as minimal as possible) so we can get a better under standing of the problem. There may be some issue in regards to how you are using the session, so a code example that doesn't work could help to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

haha, I must have been looking at it too closely for too long.  In the snippet of code that wasn't working I was calling session.commit, not session.commit().